# communicate with java server through python client

Tags: java, python, sockets, client-server

I'm trying to adjust the sample java code for an API to work with a python script. I know the java code works and can do a socket connection in python but can't figure out how to convert the string in python to be able to send the xml request successfully. I'm pretty sure I need to use struct but just haven't been able to figure it out yet in the last week.

Also I'm fairly certain I need to send the length of my request first then the request but once again I haven't been able to get anything to show a successful request on the server program.

```
public void connect(String host, int port) {
    try {
        setServerSocket(new Socket(host, port));

        setOutputStream(new DataOutputStream(getServerSocket().getOutputStream()));
        setInputStream(new DataInputStream(getServerSocket().getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Connection established.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to connect to the server.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void disconnect() {
    try {
        getOutputStream().close();
        getInputStream().close();
        getServerSocket().close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // do nothing, the program is closing
    }
}

/**
 * Sends the xml request to the server to be processed.
 * @param xml the request to send to the server
 * @return the response from the server
 */
public String sendRequest(String xml) {
    byte[] bytes = xml.getBytes();
    int size = bytes.length;
    try {
        getOutputStream().writeInt(size);
        getOutputStream().write(bytes);
        getOutputStream().flush();
        System.out.println("Request sent.");

        return listenMode();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("The connection to the server was lost.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to send a string in python:

In python2 you can just do `sock.send(s)` where `s` is the string you wanna send and `sock` is a `socket.socket`. in python3 you need to convert a string to a bytestring. You can convert using bytes(s, 'utf-8') or just prefix your string with a b as in b'abcd'.  Note that the send still has all the normal limitations of a socket send, ie it will only send as much as it can, and return a count of how many bytes went through.

The following will work as a method of a class that has a `sock` attribute.  `sock` being the socket to send through

```
def send_request(self, xml_string):
    send_string = struct.pack('i', len(xml_string)) + xml_string
    size = len(send_string)
    sent = 0
    while sent < size:
        try:
            sent += self.sock.send(send_string[sent:])
        except socket.error:
            print >> sys.stderr, "The connection to the server was lost."
            break
    else:
        print "Request sent."
```

make sure to `import` `socket`, `sys`, and `struct`

Comment: Thanks! worked like a champ actually got something back from the server, think its actually an error message but better than the nothing I was getting. Also one quick correction in send_string should be [sent:] instead of [send:]

Comment: @enderv Ah yes, thanks for the correction.  Glad it worked.  If there's something more specific you need help with on this you can edit your original post and let me know.